# DistributionGroup managedBy show only the Names not OU

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

When I use this script:

`Get-DistributionGroup -Filter {Displayname -like "DG_Group"}|Select managedBy|ft`

I get the OU together with the Name, Output:

{work.place/EUR/User/Surname, FirstName}

But I only want the Name, example Output:

{Surname, FirstName}

Comment: You can see all properties which will be return with `Get-DistributionGroup -Filter {Displayname -like "DG_Group"}|Select -Property *`. After that edit your commandline with the properties you want. just replace the `*` with the names of the properties

Comment: @guiwhatsthat Thanks, but that is not my current problem, with that method I still see the OU.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you want returned is the last part of whatever is in the ManagedBy (multivalue) property, try this (untested):

```
Get-DistributionGroup -Filter 'Displayname -like "DG_Group"' | 
    Select-Object Name, 
                  @{Name = "ManagedBy"; Expression={($_.ManagedBy | ForEach-Object {$_.Split("/")[-1]})}}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Did exacly what I wanted it to do <3